# db.query can't make a selection using integer field

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a DB with 2 tables - categories and tasks, each task have a field associated with category _id field. Problem is that selection on tasks.category_id = current category id returns empty cursor.

In debug mode can be seen that selection criteria is correct; DB fields are checked and have correct values; removing selection criteria returns the full DB correctly. 
Replacing .query to .rawQuery returns correct values, if all selection is made in the first argument. This one works well:

```
  String selection = "select * from task where category_id = " + mId;
  Cursor taskCursor = mDb.rawQuery(selection, null);
```

MainActivity:

```
 //request data from categories table
    mDb = mDbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    final Cursor categoryCursor = mDb.query(CategoryEntry.TABLE_NAME, 
        null,null, null, null, null, null);

    int mCategoryIdPos = mCursor.getColumnIndex(CategoryEntry._ID);
    int mId = mCursor.getInt(mCategoryIdPos);
 //request data from tasks table for the selected category
    String selection = TaskEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID + " = ?";
    String selectionArgs = Integer.toString(mId);
    Cursor taskCursor = mDb.query(TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, selection, 
        selectionArgs, null, null, null, null)
```

**taskCursor is empty.**

DatabaseContractClass:

```
    public static final class TaskEntry implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "task";
    public static final String COLUMN_TASK_NAME = "task_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID = "category_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_SKILL_ID = "skill_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TASK_PD = "task_pd";
    public static final String COLUMN_TASK_DATE = "task_date";
    public static final String COLUMN_TASK_PERIOD = "task_period";
    public static final String COLUMN_TASK_FREQUENCY = "task_frequency";
    public static final String COLUMN_TASK_ONBY = "task_onby";
    public static final String COLUMN_TASK_COMPLETION = 
      "task_completion";

    public static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + 
         TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COLUMN_TASK_NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, " +
            COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID + ", " +
            COLUMN_SKILL_ID + ", " +
            COLUMN_TASK_PD + ", " +
            COLUMN_TASK_DATE + ", " +
            COLUMN_TASK_PERIOD + ", " +
            COLUMN_TASK_FREQUENCY + ", " +
            COLUMN_TASK_ONBY + ", " +
            COLUMN_TASK_COMPLETION + ")";
}

public static final class CategoryEntry implements BaseColumns{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "category";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME = "category_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_PD = "category_pd";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_DATE = "category_date";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_PERIOD = 
   "category_period";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_FREQUENCY = 
     "category_frequency";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_ONBY = "category_onby";
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY_COMPLETION = 
       "category_completion";

    public static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + enter 
      code hereTABLE_NAME + " (" +
            _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COLUMN_CATEGORY_NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, " +
            COLUMN_CATEGORY_PD + ", " +
            COLUMN_CATEGORY_DATE + ", " +
            COLUMN_CATEGORY_PERIOD + ", " +
            COLUMN_CATEGORY_FREQUENCY + ", " +
            COLUMN_CATEGORY_ONBY + ", " +
            COLUMN_CATEGORY_COMPLETION + ")";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have a few issues.

## Issue 1

The selection args, 4th parameter of [query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String)), should be a `String[]` not a `String`.

i.e.

```
public Cursor query (String table, 
            String[] columns, 
            String selection, 
            String[] selectionArgs, //<<<<<<<<<<
            String groupBy, 
            String having, 
            String orderBy)
```

Try using :-

```
String selection = TaskEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{Integer.toString(mId)};
Cursor taskCursor = mDb.query(TaskEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, selection, 
    selectionArgs, null, null, null, null)
```

## Issue 2

As you have defined the **category_id** column without a TYPE, the default type affinity of NUMERIC is used and you have unfortunately hit upon a nuance where the TYPE AFFINITY matters.

In short you should apply a suitable column type (INTEGER would be correct, although TEXT would also work) as such use :-

```
    public static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COLUMN_TASK_NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, " +
            COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID + " INTEGER , " + //<<<<<<<<<<
            COLUMN_SKILL_ID + " INTEGER, " + //<<<<<<<<<<
            COLUMN_TASK_PD + ", " +
            COLUMN_TASK_DATE + ", " +
            COLUMN_TASK_PERIOD + ", " +
            COLUMN_TASK_FREQUENCY + ", " +
            COLUMN_TASK_ONBY + ", " +
            COLUMN_TASK_COMPLETION + ")";
```

- it is suggested that you include the expected type for all columns.
- Note that for the above to run you would need to delete the database or drop the table. This can be achieved by doing 1 of the following

  1. uninstalling the App and then rerunning, or
  2. clearing the App's data and then rerunning, or
  3. **IF** the **onUpgrade** method has been suitably coded, then the database version number (4th parameter of the SQLiteOpenHelper super call) can be increased.

     - suitably coded would require it to drop the table and to then create the table (typically the tables are dropped and then the onCreate method is called)
- If you cannot afford to lose data then you would need to rename the table (using the ALTER TABLE) and then create it and then load the data from the renamed original table.

## Issue 2 - Alternative Solution

An alternative to changing the column TYPE would be to use **CAST** to force a type affinity e.g. you could use :-

```
String selection = TaskEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID + " = CAST(? AS INTEGER)";
```

or

```
String selection = "CAST(" + TaskEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORY_ID  + " AS INTEGER)=?";
```

- Using either of the above doesn't require the table to be recreated, but isn't the preferable method as it's *messy*.

Comment: Great, thanks, definition of columns fixed the problem!